# CPTUI with Parent/Child categories - Template Structure

Tags: custom-post-types

Probably been asked a million times, but I cant quite wrap my head around it. I have come from ExpressionEngine and this all seems quite straight forward over there, but I am sticking with this.

I have used CPT UI plugin to create a CPT called Products. I have three parent  categories of product; granite, quartz and marble, and further sub categories in each. Pretty straight forward really?

On the front end, I want pages (I think) called Granite, Quartz and Marble, which displays the child categories which are clickable through to those child categories.

For example, the user clicks Quartz, this loads the Quartz page which displays 6 Quartz child categories which are child categories of Quartz. Clicking these then displays products of that child category.

The categories and setting up etc is easy. What I am less sure about is how to handle these using templates, despite reading the Codex.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: This structure is not really supported by WordPress out of the box, or with the template hierarchy. Categories and subcategories both only display posts (or products) that belong to that category. There is no native support for displaying subcategories instead of posts if there are subcategories to the current category. This is logic you will need to implement manually into the template for categories.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response Jacob. OK well not one to reinvent the wheel, what is the correct way to achieve this?